# send post data from js to php using ajax without type cast

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have object in javascript  and I need send this object to php using ajax.

I can "just send" this object, but my problem is that I need send object value types exactly as they are and not everything as string: meaning NULL as NULL, boolean values as boolean and so on...

Trying this:

```
var js_object= <?php echo json_encode( array("a"=>NULL, "b"=>TRUE, "C"=>1.1) ); ?>;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",        
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(js_object),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    success: function(msg){
    }
});
```

but this does not sends data to server at all. and not gives any error also. where I am  wrong  ?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. I set it up on a test page locally. Of course I stuck it inside a jquery `$(document).ready(function() {...}`. Open your chrome developer tools, look for console errors, check your network tab. I'm seeing the ajax call being called successfully, with the correct `data`.

Comment: how are you sure it's not being sent? In your JSscript you can console.log(msg) and at the top of your PHP Script do var_dump($_POST) to make sure it's getting there

Comment: Im trying `success: function(msg){ console.log(msg);
    }`  but nothing returned from server. not errors in console. if  send data without `dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",` and `stringify`, then works and sends data to server, but every value as string

Comment: Is the PHP page on the same domain as the JS?  If not, you'll need to use jsonp to make the request: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: @circusdei yes, PHP and JS are on the  same domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.
I've just add a snippet with `post` query to `httpbin.org`:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST', 
  url: '//httpbin.org/post', 
  data: JSON.stringify({name: 'test', 'null': null, 'true': true}), 
  success: onSuccess, 
  error: onError,
  dataType: 'json', 
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
});
function onSuccess(data){
  // data is parsed json response
  console.log('Request copy:', data.json);
  console.log('Full response', data);
}
function onError(xhr) {
  console.log(xhr.status, xhr.responseText);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
```

---

Server side sample script:

```
<?php
  $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $data = json_decode($json, true);
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, if I am trying `$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",        
    data:  js_object ,
    success: function(msg){
    }
});`

works, but what I am posted in question, does not.  I really not understood what's wrong here

Comment: Inspect `Network` tab. May be your server not responded. I'll add error handling.

Comment: if you get `0` status code in the error status - check the url to script. May be you use relative one instead of absolute `/some.php`.

Comment: server side is ok, because this `$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "some.php", data: js_object , success: function(msg){ } });` works and recieve response from server

Comment: Something is wrong with these:
`dataType: "json",`
   `contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",`
and
`data: JSON.stringify(js_object),`

Comment: Aren't you still inspect actual request in the Network tab??

Comment: It should have `Request Payload` with json and correct `content-type` request header

Comment: I got this error from php: `Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead.`

Comment: Then just follow these recommendations. uncomment param in php.ini and use `php://input` for parse json request data. It's not client side issue. I add sample server code.